# iloc Conditional groupby pandas fill

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-processing

Trying to conditionally fill NaN's in a dataframe, based on:
 1. value on A (done with groupby)
 2. inside groupby(A), if value is nan and is first, fill as zero and then ffill (A=a in example)
 3. inside groupby(A), if value is nan and isn't first, bfill (A=b in example)
 4. inside groupby(A), if value is nan but there's no datapoint to follow, ffill (A=c in example)

I smell ternary + lambda, but would like a pythonic way of writing it.

Basically, starting point would be:

```
df
     A    B
0    a    NaN
1    a    NaN
2    a    3.0
3    a    4.0
4    b    4.0
5    b    NaN
6    b    6.0
7    b    6.0
8    c    7.0
9    c    NaN
10   c    NaN
```

And df should become:

```
df
     A    B
0    a    0.0
1    a    0.0
2    a    3.0
3    a    4.0
4    b    4.0
5    b    6.0
6    b    6.0
7    b    6.0
8    c    7.0
9    c    7.0
10   c    7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `GroupBy.ffill`, then we are sure each groups intermediate results are filled in correctly, after that we can do a `Series.fillna` with `0`, because these are the only values left:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].ffill().fillna(0)

    A    B
0   a  0.0
1   a  0.0
2   a  3.0
3   a  4.0
4   b  4.0
5   b  4.0
6   b  6.0
7   b  6.0
8   c  7.0
9   c  7.0
10  c  7.0
```

Comment: The answer is good, my question is bad. I wanted to achieve a bfill. I'll have to edit it to highlight it accordingly. Sorry.